# CMake: Qt Project to CLion with MSVC 2017

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator, clion

I'm having a project in Qt Creator and I'm trying to port it into CLion but I found myself blocked into some problems. If any of you could help me to port this CMake project I would really appreciate it.

---

**Qt Creator**

***So, here is my setup for the Qt Creator project first:***

**Qt:** 5.14.2

**Compiler:** MSVC 2017 64-bits

[image]

Also, here are my custom paths and my build environment:

[image]

**Also, the build (install) time in Qt Creator takes around 20-30minutes.**

---

**CLion**

Now in terms of CLion and what I've tried here are the following.

[image]

and in terms of setting up the CMake:

[image]

I've also added the paths into Environment Variables from CLion

[image]

But the problem arises when I'm trying to compile the project.
I'm going to install the project via Build -> Install

[image]

After that, I need to wait for around 1h or more(even if in Qt Creator is going to take just 20-30min) to a point where the build will fail and I will receive the following error message

```
MASM : fatal error A1000: cannot open file : 4 [C:\PRJOJECT_NAME\build_clion\components\extern_crashpad\crashpad\util\crashpad_util.vcxproj]
```

but if I'm searching for that file, it exists in that folder which is specified. But the problem is that I don't understand why the same project if build with Qt Creator is working but not vice versa. Could any of you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like QT Creator is using Ninja as a generator and CLion is using MSVC.

Try -G Ninja in your CLion CMake Options text box. Make sure Ninja is in a path accessible by CMake.

Comment: What do you mean by Qt Creator using Ninja? I mean in Qt Creator I've created a kit that has MSCV 2017. Dose doesn't mean that it will use an MSCV as a generator?

Comment: A generator is different than a kit. Your QT Creator CMake project is using Ninja to generate build files. Your CLion CMake project is using Visual Studio to generate build files. Have you tried changing the -G "Visual Studio..." command to -G Ninja in CLion yet? @Mircea

Comment: actually yes I've tried and it's working, I've just forgotten to accept your answer.

Comment: But I do have one more question if you know and if you could help me. After I'm building this code it's going to result in an exe file. In Qt Creator, I have an option in the configuration to run to execute that executable as a Custom Executable from where I can specify the working directory and executable file. How can I do that also in CLion because I can't find anything like that?

Comment: Click the edit configuration button on your toolbar. https://i.stack.imgur.com/07NDs.png

And change the working directory for your executable target.

Comment: It would work... but I don't have a Target to do this. I do have just the Executable and the Working directory